Doubt in proof of Second Existence Theorem for Weak Solutions
I have the same doubt as in here, but none of the answers there seem to make things clearer to me. When Evan proves the Second Existence Theorem for Weak Solutions, he asserts on Step 4 that:

$v-K^*v=0$ holds if and only if $v$ satisfies $B[u,v]=0$ for all $u\in H^1_0$

To fix Evan's notation, $K:L^2\rightarrow H_0^1\subseteq L^2$ is given implictly by the equation (which has a unique solution due to Lax-Milgram):
$$B_\gamma[Kl/\gamma,s]=(l,s)\quad \forall s\in H_0^1$$
$$B[Kl/\gamma,s]=(l-Kl,s)\quad \forall s\in H_0^1$$
Fair enough. Now I notice that $v-K^*v=0$ if and only if for every $l\in L^2$:
$$(v-K^*v,l)=0\Leftrightarrow(v,l)-(v,Kl)=0\Leftrightarrow(l-Kl,v)=0$$
IF $v\in H_0^1$, THIS HOLDS IFF:
$$B[Kl/\gamma,v]=0$$
Now to finish things off I need density of the image of $K$ in $H_0^1$. But even worse, I have no guarantee $v\in H_0^1$ as $K^*$ if defined in all of $(L^2)^*\approx L^2$. How do I deal with this?

EDIT: Maybe only $\Leftarrow$ holds but this is all we need. Every solution of $B(v,u)=0$ for all $u\in H_0^1$ satisfies $v-K^* v=0$ due to the computations above. The solutions of $B[v,u]=0$ form a subspace of $N(I-K^*)$ which is finite dimensional ($K$ is compact, hence $K^*$ is compact by Schauder and we use Fredholm). Hence, this subspace is finite dimensional which is what the Theorem claims. Maybe the converse doesn't hold and we really have a stric containment:
$$\{B[v,u]=0 \quad \forall u\in H_0^1\}\subset N(I-K^*)$$

Could you explain the notation more? What is $\gamma$, and what are the definitions of $B$ and $B_\gamma$? And what is $l$ in your first two displayed equations?

@user1149748, sure. $B(u,v)=\int_U\sum_{i,j}a^{i,j}(x) u_{x_i}v_{x_j}+\sum_i b^i(x)u_{x_i}v+c(x) uv dx$. $\gamma$ is chosen so that $$\beta \Vert u\Vert_{H_0^2}^2\leq B(u,u)+\gamma(u,u)=:B_{\gamma}(u,u)$$ Ow, and by $l$ I mean any element in $L^2$ (that is where $K$ is defined).

If I remember correctly one needs to explicitly compute $K^*$ and show that it is defined by $B_\gamma[s, K^*l ] = \gamma (s,l) $ $\forall s\in H^1_0$.

Thank you for the hint, @daw. I would be grately appreciate your help in providing a more detailed answer though. I am not quite sure how to explicitly find $K^$ (or $K$ for that matter, as $K$ is given as a solution to an integral equation)... Also $K^ f(v)=f(K(v))$, so it seems that knowing $K$ gives all information about $K^*$.

You need to find $K^*$: first, $u = Kf$ if and only if
$$
B_\gamma(u,v)  = \gamma(f,v) \quad \forall v\in H^1_0.
$$
Take $g\in L^2$. Define $z$ to be the unique solution of
$$
B_\gamma(v,z) = \gamma(g,v) \quad \forall v\in H^1_0.
$$
Then
$$
\gamma (g,Kf) = \gamma (g,u) = B_\gamma(u,z) = \gamma(f,z).
$$
Since $f$ was arbitrary, this proves $z = K^*g$.
Then $z = K^*z$ if and only if
$$
B_\gamma(v,z) = \gamma(z,v) \quad \forall v\in H^1_0,
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
B(v,z) = 0\quad \forall v\in H^1_0.
$$

WOW! This is just brilliant. Extremely clear.
